# How to update a group of combo boxes using Loops

Tags: vb.net

I have a form with combo boxes (cmbPort#) to select up to 8 serial ports. I want to first clear the item list for each, populate them with currently available system ports, and then add the option "Off" to each list. Finally, to set each combo box according to defaults saved in string spName(). I created a GroupBox (gBox1) and dragged each cmbPort onto it but I'm not sure how to reference the controls on it. I'm using VB 2015.

Can you help with VB.NET code to use loops ("For Each" or similar) to do this more efficiently?

```
    Private Sub frmProp_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    cmbPort1.Items.Clear()
    ...
    cmbPort8.Items.Clear()

    For Each sp As String In My.Computer.Ports.SerialPortNames
        cmbPort1.Items.Add(sp)
        ...
        cmbPort8.Items.Add(sp)
    Next

    cmbPort1.Items.Add("Off")
    ...
    cmbPort8.Items.Add("Off")

    cmbPort1.Text = spName(1)
    ...
    cmbPort8.Text = spName(8)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Loops are an incredibly useful tool to master. I pitched here some code so you can get the idea, but I was working out of IDE so you might have to apply some fixes to this code to make it work as you want it to.

The main idea is that you shouldn't have to write a line more than once. If you multiply the same operation on several lines of code, you create potential problems for the future. Loops and subs are really helpful to prevent this kind of issues.

```
Private Sub frmProp_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'This is for later
    Dim cmbIndex As Integer = 1

    'You basically do the same operations for every Combobox in your list, son only one loop needed
    For Each cmbPort As ComboBox In {cmbPort1, cmbPort2, cmbPort3 [...] cmbPort8} 'this is a way to declare an array
        'Clear
        cmbPort.Items.Clear()

        'Add SerialPortNames
        For Each sp As String In My.Computer.Ports.SerialPortNames
            cmbPort.Items.Add(sp)
        Next

        'Add "Off"
        cmbPort.Items.Add("Off")

        'This last one is a little bit trickier because you want to match numbers
        'This is the place where you get errors when something doesn't go as planned
        'If you need to keep it inside the loop here's a way to achieve that, but honestly I would't do that
        'Instead I would suggest that you take this part out of the loop and do it manually
        If spName(cmbIndex) IsNot Nothing Then cmbPort.Text = spName(cmbIndex)
        cmbIndex += 1
    Next
End Sub
```

You shouldn't consider efficiency into this equation, as this operation will not be called all the time, only on load. I mean: you should always do things in the best way you can, but optimization is sometimes the enemy of good, readable code.